# Three.js - No performance gain using buffer geometry

Tags: javascript, performance, three.js, buffer

I had a look at this Three.js example: [webgl_performance](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_performance.html)

I then added the following line to convert the model into a buffer geometry:

```
var buffer = THREE.BufferGeometryUtils.fromGeometry( geometry );
```

I expected this to improve performance *(buffer geometry magic y'know)* but I am getting exactly the same fps (~20) in both the original and the altered version.

Original: [webgl_performance](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_performance.html)

Altered: [webgl_performance_buffer_geometry](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53738503/no%20performance%20gain/webgl_performance_buffer_geometry.html)

I am just curious why I did not get any improvements. Does the json loader already use buffer geometries? Shouldn't I always convert to buffer geometries if possible?

Comment: Zoomed out, I get a frame rate of 17 for your original case vs 52 for the altered one.

Comment: Really? WOW! Okay.. that is weird that I don't get that improvement.
I am gonna take your word for it and use buffer geometry whenever possible.

Comment: I get around 32 fps in the first, and around 37 in the second. But any of them hits 100% on GPU usage (around 70%) - GTX650

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance should be pretty much the same in that example. That example is mostly measuring the speed of the scenegraph update.

If anything it should be saving on memory.

Comment: But isn't one of the reasons to use buffer geometry that it can be send to the gpu faster?

Comment: Yes, but only the first time.

Comment: Alright. In that case I keep reading until I understand the use-case for buffer geometry.

Comment: Lower memory footprint :)